# Strong divisibility of Lucas sequences

Tags: nt.number-theory, recurrences

Let $a$ and $b$ be relatively prime integers and let $u_n$ be their associate Lucas sequence, i.e., the second order linear recurrence sequence satisfying $u_0 = 0$, $u_1 = 1$ and $u_{n+2} = au_{n+1} + bu_n$, for each nonnegative integer $n$.

It is well know that $(u_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ is a strong divisibility sequence, i.e., it holds 
$$(\bullet) \quad \gcd(u_m, u_n) = u_{\gcd(m,n)} ,$$
for all the integers $m,n \geq 0$ (put $\gcd(0,0) := 0$). 
This in turn implies that
$$(\star) \quad m \mid n \Rightarrow u_m \mid u_n ,$$
for all the integers $m,n \geq 0$.

My question is: Are there some nice hypothesis under which also the reverse implication holds in ($\star$) ?

Note that from ($\bullet$), we get
$$ u_m \mid u_n \Rightarrow u_m = \gcd(u_m, u_n) = u_{\gcd(m,n)} ,$$
so if $(u_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ is injective then $m = \gcd(m,n)$ and thus $m \mid n$. So my question can be also answered if one gets some nice hypothesis under which $(u_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ is injective.

Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: $u_n$ grows exponentially (except in trivial cases) so you get eventual injectivity. That's the best you can expect, e.g. $a=b=1$ (Fibonacci) has $u_2=u_1$.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch Maybe better than abstract "eventual injectivity" would be an effective bound, in terms of $a$ and $b$, for when injectivity starts. This should be feasible. Of course, for higher order linear recurrences with many largest eigenvalues, it's much harder.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch $u_n$ do not grows exponentially in many non trivial cases, for example: let $a = 2A$ and $b = 1 - 2A^2$, for some integer $A \neq 0$. Then the roots $\alpha,\beta$ of the characteristic polynomial $x^2 - ax - b$ are such that $|\alpha| = |\beta| = 1$.

Comment: What is the exact question? Is it: "When does a sequence of integers satisfy $u_m|u_n \Rightarrow m|n?$" Certainly one can set $u_1=c$ at the expense of making everything a multiple of $c$ but not of $c^2$. Or is it "When does a sequence given by a linear recurrence with constant coefficients satisfy $u_m|u_n \Rightarrow m|n?$ If $u_i$ is one such, then $u_i^t$ is another, although with a higher order recurrence.

Comment: @Fry If $|\alpha| = |\beta| = 1$, then $|b| = |\alpha||\beta| = 1$ and for the roots to be complex $a^2 +4b <0$ so $b=-1, |a| < 2$.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch Right, clearly I have done some mistake in my computation.

Comment: @AaronMeyerowitz The question is: "When does a Lucas sequence satisfy $u_m \mid u_n \Rightarrow m \mid n$.

Comment: I think I was optimistic in my eventual injectivity. It's clear when the roots of the characteristic equation are real but not when they are complex. But to answer the question it enough to establish that if $k|m$ and $u_m=u_k$, then $m=k$. For that, even in the complex case, the growth is fast enough so that this implication holds for $m$ large enough.

Comment: @Felipe The eventual injectivity of $|u_k|$ seems highly likely to be true, and is interesting. However I do not see why the growth rate ensures this, see my answer below. Also, even if we had injectivity provided $n \gt a^2+b^2$, that would not rule out something like $u_{32}(a,b)=\pm u_{16}(a,b)$ with $a \gt 6.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a method to solve this problem. We recall the primitive prime factor theorem

**Theorem 2.3.1** (Florian Luca, Effective methods for diophantine equations)
If $k \notin \{1,2,3,4,6\}$, then $u_k$ has a [primitive prime factor](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimitivePrimeFactor.html) except when $(a,\Delta,k)$, where $\Delta = a^2 + 4b$, is one of the following triples:

$$(1, 5, 5), (1, -7, 5), (2, -40, 5), (1, -11,5), (1, -15, 5), (12, -76, 5), (12, -1364, 5),$$
$$(1, -7, 7), (1, -19, 7),$$
$$(2, -24, 8), (1, -7, 8),$$
$$(2,-8,10), (5, -3, 10),$$
$$(1, 5, 12), (1, -7, 12), (1, -11, 12), (2, -56, 12), (1, -15, 12), (1, -19, 12),$$
$$(1, -7, 13),$$
$$(1, -7, 18),$$
$$(1, -7, 30).$$

Now, let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers such that $u_m \mid u_n$ but $m \nmid n$.
From $(\bullet)$ we have that
$$u_m = \gcd(u_m, u_n) = u_d ,$$
where $d = \gcd(m,n) < m$. It follows that $u_m$ has not a primitive prime factor.
From Theorem 2.3.1 then or $m \in \{1,2,3,4,6\}$ or $(a,\Delta,m)$ is one of the triples listed above.
In each of these cases, we can (patiently) check if actually there exist or not a divisor $d$ of $m$ such that $u_m = u_d$.

Comment: Nice to know this result. I found this link for the book: https://math.dartmouth.edu/~m105f12/lucaHungary1.pdf Luca gives the history which is kind of interesting and stretches from 1892 (for integer roots) to 2001 (for complex roots.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a conjectured answer along with a few results and observations.

- The first few values are $u_{{1}}=1,u_{{2}}=a,u_{{3}}={a}^{2}+b,u_{{4}}={a}^{3}+2\,ab,$$u_{{5}}={
  a}^{4}+3\,{a}^{2}b+{b}^{2},u_{{6}}={a}^{5}+4\,{a}^{3}b+3\,a{b}^{2}
  $
- In general, $$u_{n+1}=\sum_0^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}\binom{n-i}{i}a^{n-2i}b^{i}$$

> The desired divisibility condition fails in the following cases. I *conjecture* that these are the only exceptions
>
> - When $a=0$ we have $u_4 \mid u_6$ as both are zero.
> - When $a=\pm 1$ we have $u_2=a \mid u_3$.
> - When $b=-a^2 \pm 1$ we have $u_3=\pm 1 \mid u_4$
> - When $b=\frac{-a^2 \pm 1}{2}$ We have $u_4 \mid u_6$ since $u_4=a(a^2+2b)=\pm u_2$

- $u_{2i}=u_i\left(u_{i+1}+bu_{i-1}\right)$ and in general, $u_{i+j}=u_iu_{j+1}+bu_{i-1}u_j$

As noted, since $\gcd(u_m,u_n)=u_{\gcd(m,n)}$, the only way to have $u_m \mid u_n $ and yet not have $m \mid n$ is to have $|u_m|=|u_k|$  where $k=\gcd(m,n) \lt m.$, Writing $m=jk$ this becomes $$|u_{jk}|=|u_{k}|$$

- Since $u_n(-a,b)=\pm u_n(a,b)$ we may restrict attention to $a \ge 2$.
- The most promising case would seem to be $|u_{2k}|=|u_k|$ Where we would need $v_k=\frac{u_{2k}}{u_k}=u_{k+1}+bu_{k-1}$ to be $\pm 1.$ If we define $v_0=2$ then these values $2,a,a^2+2b,a^3+3ab,\cdots$ also satisfy $v_{k+2}=av_{k+1}+bv_k$ and have $v_i \mid v_{i\ell}$ for odd $\ell$. In particular $|v_k|=1$ is impossible (for $a \ge 2$) when $k$ has an odd  divisor. This leaves only powers of $2.$ An example: $$v_8={a}^{8}+8\,{a}^{6}b+20\,{a}^{4}{b}^{2}+16\,{a}^{2}{b}^{3}+2\,{b}^{4}.$$ An integer solution of $v_8=\pm 1$ would require $a$ to be a divisor of $b^4 \pm 1$

  - Further thoughts on $v_k=\pm 1$: Certainly the odd $k$ are ruled out by $v_1=a\mid v_k.$ When $v_2=a^2+2b$ has $v_2=\pm 1$ one could examine the case that also $v_{2k}=\pm 1$ for some prime $k.$
- Although I can believe that $k \mapsto |u_k|$ is eventually (and perhaps very quickly) injective, I'm not sure that the growth rate alone is enough. In the case $a=1,b=-2,$ the indices $197 \le i \le 214$ in order of increasing $|u_i|$ are $201, 198, 214, 197, 199, 200, 204, 202, 203, 206, 209, 205, 207, 208, 211, 210, 212, 213$ Also, for $a=5,b=-7$, $u_{293} \lt u_{289}.$ On the other hand, an exception would need to be $|u_{jk}|=|u_k|$ for $j \ge 3$ or $|u_{2k}|=|u_{k}|$ for $k$ a power of two.
- Here are some (maybe all) sporadic cases of $u_n(1,b)=\pm 1:$  $u_5(1,-2),u_{13}(1,-2),u_5(1,-3),u_7(1,-5).$